# Applet Java en Navegador

Tags: java, web

Tengo un applet que deseo ejecutar en mi Aplicación ASP.NET, estuve buscando como cargarla y encontré un método que me funciona, lo ejecuto desde jscript con:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = {
        code: 'Applet.class',
        archive: 'Applets/miapplet.jar', 
        width: 325, height: 325 
    };
    var parameters = { fontSize: 16 };
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version); 
</script>
```

Ya me manda a llamar al applet, pero me marca el siguiente error:

```
SecurityException
attempted to open sandboxed jar miapplet.jar as a Trusted-Library
```

He leído que tal vez sea algo de la firma del jar, uso la opción "self-sign by generated key" (ya que no conozco otro método y ese está por default).
También he leído que basta con quitar la opcion Trusted = true pero no me funciona. Alguna idea que me podría ayudar??

P.D Uso la versión más reciente de java, ejecuto la aplicación con NetBeans y funciona perfecto, y visualizo mi sitio web desde internet explorer, ya que en Chrome me dice que no soporta java.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu `Manifest`?

Answer (score 1):

Los Famosos Applets de antaño, el problema:
Después de la versión 7 de Java (Java 7 Update 51) los navegadores no permiten que tu aplicación corra si no esta firmada por "una autoridad de confianza".
Ademas debes de editar el MANIFEST de tu aplicación con ciertas características, para que pueda correr.

Puedes intentar consiguiendo una llave de prueba por 2 meses, eso hice yo para desarrollar mi aplicación en pruebas, firmas el jar con el certificado, baja la seguridad de la consola de java.

Y trata de correrlo en IE o Firefox, Chrome ya no acepta applets por su baja seguridad.

Mas info: [¿Por qué en la versión más reciente de Java mi configuración de seguridad bloquea las aplicaciones Java?](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Lo que pasa es que lo que en realidad deseo hacer es manejar un lector de huellas digitales en un sitio web. Por lo que leí eso no se puede hacer, a menos que usara un programa intermediario y mandarlo a llamar en mi sitio web. Por eso intenté lo del applet, pero ahora no puedo ejecutarlo en mi sitio web.

Comment: No sé si en vez de un applet pueda ejecutar alguna aplicación windows forms o si se pueda hacer en wpf

Comment: Si lo que deseas es implementarlo en web pero con la tecnología de java, puedes usar Java EE, los jsp y demás, que lenguajes maneja el lector?, anteriormente tuve que crear un programa en java para imprimir desde una epson pos printer, a veces no cuentan con muchos drivers.

Comment: Pues en realidad desearía usar C# y ASP.NET ya que es la tecnología que trabajo, pero por lo que estuve investigando no se puede hacer :(